# How to correctly move jquery script to external file

Tags: import

I have a jQuery floating navbar plugin that works fine when all the code is inserted in the head. However the ammount of code in the head became unmanageable so I put the code in the root directory in a file called sscroll.js.

I have tried to include the file the following ways but they don't work. (No errors are coming up on firebug)

`<?php wp_enqueue_script('sscroll', 'sscroll.js', array('jquery')); ?>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sscroll.js"></script>
<script>
$('#sidecontainer').stickyfloat({duration: 400 });
</script>
```

>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sscroll.js">$('#sidecontainer').stickyfloat({duration: 400 });</script>
```

>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sscroll.js"></script>
```

I prefer using the enqueue script, but I'll be happy with anything that works.
Any suggestions welcome. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute URL - you say the script is in the root directory, is that the root directory of WordPress? If so;

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'sscroll', site_url( 'sscroll.js' ), array( 'jquery' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Hi DeadMedic - thanks! adding site_url( did the trick!